# Por que un media query si funciona en chrome pero no en firefox?

Tags: html, css, estilos

Hola pues como tal mi duda es esa, en my styles.css pongo un media query de forma

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
h1{
    font-size: 4rem;
}
h2{
    font-size: 3.6rem;
}
p{
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}
```

}

Y en chrome y todos sus derivados funciona correctamente cuando pongo por ejemplo la resolucion del ipad 768*600 Y en firefox no funciona hasta que uso el media query bajandole un pixel, es decir de esta forma

```
@media (min-width: 767px) {
h1{
    font-size: 4rem;
}
h2{
    font-size: 3.6rem;
}
p{
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}
```

}

Alguna idea del por que no funciona de la misma forma??

Comment: Did you set the viewport tag in the html?

Comment: @Juan Yeah, content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"